# Python nongreedy second match

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `s = "a{asdfgh{asf}xvc}defg}des}"`
I want to extract the part `"{asdfgh{asf}xvc}"` using regular expressions.
I have used the regex match

```
p = re.compile('(\{[\w|\W]+?\})')
```

but it will extract `"{asdfgh{asf}"` .
What is the correct regex for extracting the part `"{asdfgh{asf}xvc}"`.

Also:
What I am asking is for the second occurence match for '}' char.
How can I match for nth occurence.

Comment: This is going to get complex really, really fast. Are you certain regular expressions are the right tool for your job? Perhaps you need a parser instead (`pyparsing` and friends).

Comment: give us an example for nth occurance..`{}` are not balanced..are you showing us partial data

Comment: Use normal looping and count the number of open bracket and close bracket to extract the string. Python regex is not up for the job.

Comment: `[\w|\W]` means "alphanumeric or not alphanumeric". Therefore this will match any character. In that case you should just use `.`. Also, `+` means "one or more" while `?` means "zero or one". If you're trying to say "zero or many" you should use `*`.

Comment: @acattle: The `?` right after the `+` makes the `+` non-greedy, which is why it stops matching at the first `}`.

Comment: @AlanMoore then wouldn't removing the `?` solve Vinod's problem? Actually, changing it to `*` would too, depending on if `{}` is a valid match...

Comment: @acattle: No, changing it to `*` or `+` will make it consume all but the last closing brace, which is two braces too many in this example.  If you don't know how deep the nesting goes, you can't solve this problem with a single regex.  Not in Python, anyway.

Comment: @AlanMoore then the OP needs the input to be properly formatted then I'm throwing my support behind the parser suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out...

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'a{asdfgh{asf}xvc}defg}des}'
>>> p = re.compile('(\{[\w|\W]+?\}.+?\})')
>>> print p.findall(s)
['{asdfgh{asf}xvc}']
```

If you need to match one more, just append `.+?\}` to the re.

```
>>> p = re.compile('(\{[\w|\W]+?\}.+?\}.+?\})')
>>> print p.findall(s)
['{asdfgh{asf}xvc}defg}']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
\{.*?\{[^{}]*\}.*?\}
```

---

For Nth occurance

```
(\{[^}{]*){N}[^{}]*([^{}]*\}){N}
```

So

for N=1 would match `{xyz}`

for N=2 would match `{x{y}z}`

Comment: It assumes pyramid structure `{{{}}}`, but something like this `{{}{}}` is going to fail. You should state the limitation in your answer, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh from his example i guess the input would always be in the form `{{}}`..he needs to clarify on that...

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ structure is always like {{}}

Answer (score 0):

To search for the second occurrence of `}` after the first `{`, build an RE like this:

{`<non-} text>` } `<non-} text>` }

Expressing `<non-} text>` as `[^}]*`, we get:

```
    {[^}]*}[^}]*}
```

If you need to distinguish `{}{}` from `{{}}`, things get more complicated. In general, REs are not a good tool for dealing with nesting: There is a deep mathematical result that makes it so. Any supposed work-around is a kludge that will get too complex quickly. But if you *know* what your bracket pattern looks like and you just want to get to the second `}`, this will do it.

Comment: The theoretical regex won't be able to do it, but most of the modern languages has a regex engine that is more powerful than theoretical regex. Those with recursive pattern can solve bracket matching problem. (Not that I endorse using recursive regex, though).

Comment: Well, you're right. Recursive REs allow you to hide an entire pushdown automaton behind them, which calls your RE multiple times. And Perl's "lazy regular subexpressions" allow you to embed arbitrary perl code inside the RE, so they're actually Turing complete! But the RE notation can't keep up with this kind of games, hence the last part of my answer. (Not that ordinary RE's don't get out of hand...)

Answer (score 0):

To match from `{` to the second appearance of `}` you could use

```
\{(?:[^}]*\}){2}
```

To match from `{` to the nth appearance of `}` you could use

```
\{(?:[^}]*\}){n}
```

Where `(?:[^}]*\})` is a non-capturing group which `{n}` means must appear n number of times consecutively to produce a match.